# ArangoDB Remove element from nested array

Tags: arangodb

I am trying to remove an array element from a nested structure.

For example element with ID 21 needs to be removed from the document.

```
FOR doc in [
{
    _key:1,
    Lvl1:[
        {ID:1, Lvl2:[{ID:10,Text:"A"},{ID:11,Text:"B"},{ID:12,Text:"C"}]},
        {ID:2, Lvl2:[{ID:20,Text:"D"},{ID:21,Text:"E"},{ID:22,Text:"F"}]},
    ]
}]
    
return {_key:doc._key ,Lvl1:doc.Lvl1[*].Lvl2[* FILTER CURRENT.ID!=21]}
```

The fitler basically works, but the document structure is not preserved so I cannot perform an update on **Lvl1** of the document.

**Output**

```json
[
  {
    "_key": 1,
    "Lvl1": [
      [
        {
          "ID": 10,
          "Text": "A"
        },
        {
          "ID": 11,
          "Text": "B"
        },
        {
          "ID": 12,
          "Text": "C"
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "ID": 20,
          "Text": "D"
        },
        {
          "ID": 22,
          "Text": "F"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
FOR doc in [
{
    _key:1,
    Lvl1:[
        {ID:1, Lvl2:[{ID:10,Text:"A"},{ID:11,Text:"B"},{ID:12,Text:"C"}]},
        {ID:2, Lvl2:[{ID:20,Text:"D"},{ID:21,Text:"E"},{ID:22,Text:"F"}]},
    ]
}]
    
return {_key:doc._key ,Lvl1:(
    FOR item IN doc.Lvl1
    RETURN {ID: item.ID,Lvl2: item.Lvl2[* FILTER CURRENT.ID!=21]}
)}
```

Using the nested FOR works as a `map` operation and can give you more control over the output.